# OSX application without storyboard or xib files using Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything useful on the Internet - I wanted to know, what code I actually have to type for initializing an application without using storyboard or XIB files in Swift. I know I have to have a `.swift` file called `main`. But I don't know what to write in there (like do I need autoreleasepool or something like that?). For example, what would I do for initializing an `NSMenu` and how would I add a `NSViewController` to the active window (iOS's similar `.rootViewController` doesn't help). Thanks for any help ;)

Edit:
I actually don't want to use `@NSApplicationMain` in front of the `AppDelegate`. I'd rather know what exactly happens there and then do it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you ever want to avoid `@NSApplicationMain`, but this question sure does have good educational value behind the scenes!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

if you don't want to have the @NSApplicationMain attribute, do:

1. have a file main.swift
2. add following top-level code:

   ```
    import Cocoa

    let delegate = AppDelegate() //alloc main app's delegate class
    NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate //set as app's delegate
    NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv) //start of run loop       

    // Old versions:
    //  NSApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV)
    //  NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv);
   ```

the rest should be inside your app delegate. e.g.:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var newWindow: NSWindow?
    var controller: ViewController?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 300, 300), styleMask: .resizable, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        controller = ViewController()
        let content = newWindow!.contentView! as NSView
        let view = controller!.view
        content.addSubview(view)
        
        newWindow!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

then you have a viewController

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController : NSViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,100,100))
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.borderWidth = 2
        view.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I then display several view controllers on the window? Or should I use different windows hiding and showing when they are needed? Or is there even another effort to do this?

Comment: your window could have NSWindowControllers and in there you could add views... I don't get your issue :D

Comment: I agree with leonardo that for more complex stuff you should use xibs -- I don't quite often but if you're stuck on this level, I would do so

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have to try it out later. By the way - I do not need to do anything like autoreleasepool (I saw this on other approaches from 2010 or somewhen like that)?

Comment: no you don't need that. since you don't have c launching swift (in 2010 code you had c launching objC)

Comment: sorry this isn't 'write all my code for me' - your question was 100% answered and you can ask either different specific questions or (better maybe) try some tutorials

Comment: It's `func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification)` in Swift 3.1. Pure copy and paste led to some confusion on my part.

Comment: When I try this with Xcode 9 the app terminates complaining that it cannot find a xib file. Where do I tell NSApplication not to use a xib file?

Comment: In the info.plist

Answer (score 18):

The top level code sample above no longer works in recent versions of Xcode.   Instead use this:

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate() //alloc main app's delegate class
NSApplication.shared().delegate = delegate //set as app's delegate

let ret = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

Comment: No longer works in Swift 4. I spent hours and still no luck programmatically create a window with pure swift. Apple makes is so hard to do it (\read no official getting started guide without storyboard )

Comment: @Kun Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @BohdanSavych I did, `shared` is now a computed property, so drop the parentheses after that.

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 4 it has changed slightly yet again,

The main file must have

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate

NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

The AppDelegate must be

```
import Cocoa


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var newWindow: NSWindow?
    var controller: ViewController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 300, 300), styleMask: .resizable, backing: .buffered, defer: false)

        controller = ViewController()
        let content = newWindow!.contentView! as NSView
        let view = controller!.view
        content.addSubview(view)

        newWindow!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

The view controller is the same

Comment: For anyone like me looking to make window showing title frame `window = NSWindow(contentRect: winSize, styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled], backing: .buffered, defer: false)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Swift 5, and although my app works with the code from Noskcaj's answer,  I see a bunch of `[Nib Loading] Failed to connect...` errors from existing nib files. I fixed it by using this in my main.swift instead:

```swift
import Cocoa

autoreleasepool {
 let delegate = AppDelegate()
 // NSApplication delegate is a weak reference,
 // so we have to make sure it's not deallocated.
 withExtendedLifetime(delegate, {
     let application = NSApplication.shared
     application.delegate = delegate
     application.run()
     application.delegate = nil
 })
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239088