# How to open a new Window in swift from a console project?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to open a new Window in Swift with Cocoa (for Mac) without creating a "Cocoa Application" project but manually by creating a "Console" project.
I created a console swift project, and I tried to put this code

```
import AppKit

print("Creating a windows manually")
let vue = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 272))
let win = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x:100,y:100,width: 480, height:272), styleMask: .borderless, backing: .retained, defer: false)
```

But the windows is not shown after running. What do should I do to make it open and stay open ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX application without storyboard or xib files using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792722/osx-application-without-storyboard-or-xib-files-using-swift)

Comment: No i tried your link and the code on your link does not work.

Comment: Post your code and the problem and we'll try to help.